# How to find a specific value in a website table using VBA (Solution Found)

Tags: excel, vba

Solution has be found. I have replaced the code with what I have that works in case anyone every needs to do anything similar. I appreciate all of the help from those who responded.

I asked a question yesterday trying to get an excel macro to grab some website data and throw back a specific value from the website. I believe I am going to have to scrape the website and dump the information into a new sheet and then work to snag the data that I need. The below code does not throw back any errors but it will not paste any data into the new sheet. Site loads and a new sheet called GCMP is added. I located this sample from http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?47374-VBA-getElementsByTagName-Issues. The issue may be with the `Delement.className = "dist_body"` not knowing what data to pull. The site used dist_body, mdist, tbody(table).

```
Sub gcmData()

Dim htm As Object
Dim Tr As Object
Dim Td As Object
Dim Tab1 As Object
Dim rSearch As Object

'Grabs URL Tool Data Sheet
Web_URL = ['Tool Data'!B2]

'Create HTMLFile Object
Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")

'Get the WebPage Content to HTMLFile Object
With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
.Open "GET", Web_URL, False
.send
HTML_Content.body.innerHTML = .responseText 'this is the highlighted part for the error
End With

Sheets.Add.Name = "GCMP"
Sheets("GCMP").Range("A1").Select

Column_Num_To_Start = 1
iRow = 2
iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
iTable = 0

'Loop Through Each Table and Download it to Excel in Proper Format
For Each Tab1 In HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")
With HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")(iTable)
For Each Tr In .Rows
For Each Td In Tr.Cells
Sheets("GCMP").Cells(iRow, iCol).Select
Sheets("GCMP").Cells(iRow, iCol) = Td.innerText
iCol = iCol + 1
Next Td
iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
iRow = iRow + 1
Next Tr
End With

iTable = iTable + 1
iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
iRow = iRow + 1
Next Tab1
'Takes the data pulled from the website and searchs for the cell with Total. It pulls the cell value next to it removes
'the comma and mi. Then pops a test msg box with the value, then it divides the number by two and pops another msgbox to
' make sure it can be manipulated as a number for further use.

On Error Resume Next
 With Sheets("GCMP").Range("A1").Select
  Dim s As String
  Dim n As String
  Cells.Select
    Set rSearch = Selection.Find(what:="Total", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        Lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Activate
        s = ActiveCell.Value
        s = Replace(s, ",", "")
        s = Replace(s, " mi", "")
        MsgBox s
        n = s / 2
        MsgBox n

End With
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Sheets("GCMP").Delete
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: trying looping through the rows and columns (cells of each row) for the table. You may need to do some trial and error before you find out which row and cell (column) the information is stored in.

Comment: Where is `odiv` defined and set? As written this would sort of-ish dump all data in any HTML table in the web document into a variable called `stabledata`. I would imagine this would need some massive tweaking to go after the exact piece of info you are looking for.

Comment: Also, which line is this breaking on? There are a lot of possible spots for failure here, especially if this code is copypasta.

Comment: It is breaking on the third line stating that the dist_body is empty. I have used a few different macros to try and do this but each come back on the same line. Not sure of that is common. I can add the original code I used but it opens IE pulls the data and then closes. Well it o suppose to. It hangs up at the same spot.

Comment: Make sure that you implement `Option Explicit` in your code. With this, you would have seen that you never declared `odiv` - and as far as the code you provided to us, `odiv` is `Nothing`.

Comment: YOu don't appear to be using `oTbl` so just comment out that line. Not sure what kind of tag a `dist_body` would be anyway. In fact, I think you could comment out everything before that `stabledata = stabledata & vbCrLf` and still get what you need. Just guessing though.